# Javascript - key and value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wish to store some data dynamically in an array, using Javascript. My goal is to save a configuration, that the user has specified, and later store it in my database.

I am trying to create a array like this:

```
var config = [];
config.push({id:100,name:'Yashwant',age:30}); 
config.push({id:200,name:'Mahesh',age:35});
```

However, when I print out the `config` array, like this:

```
alert(config);
```

it prints:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I store and push values to my array, dynamically?

**EDIT::** Seems like I am storing the values correctly. How can I access it?

Comment: Why do you think that there is an issue in your code?

Comment: This `{id:100,name:'Yashwant',age:30}` is being consider an object, you are storing it right. `[object Object],[object Object]` is the string() representation. I believe you may be asking about how to read the objects...

Comment: How can I access the array data then?

Comment: You can access to object properties by `alert(config[0].id); alert(config[0].name);`

Comment: @Hokusai that returns "undefined"

Comment: `config[0].id`, `config[0].name` for first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert casts the `config` parameter to string. If you want to see the value for debugging purposes, it is better to use `console.log(config)`.

Or you could use `JSON.stringify(config)` to convert it to JSON string.

To access the values, you can do this: `console.log(config[0].age, config[1].age);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print values of any javascript object you can use JSON class to either stringify object data or parse stringified data (JSON) back to object.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(config));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context to your answer. While your answer may be correct, providing some background about *why* this is the answer or *how* it fixes OP's issue is encouraged.